# Firebase indexOn security & rules not working

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-security, firebase-realtime-database

I'm getting this error in xcode:

Using an unspecified index. Consider adding ".indexOn": "members/rsenov" at /groups to your security rules for better performance

This is my JSON data structure:

```
{
"groups" : {
  "-KB422VV21cPzpgi1wF1" : {
    "author" : "rsenov",
    "members" : {
      "rsenov" : true
    },
    "name" : "Item 1"
  },
  "-KB423lni1Iptn2fGwi1" : {
    "author" : "rsenov",
    "members" : {
      "rsenov" : true
    },
    "name" : "Item 2"
  },
  "-KB48kVOz4yTfdE86Ub7" : {
    "author" : "senovi",
    "members" : {
      "senovi" : true
    },
    "name" : "Asd"
  }
},
"users" : {
  "rsenov" : {
    "email" : "rsenov",
    "groups" : {
      "-KB422VV21cPzpgi1wF1" : true,
      "-KB423lni1Iptn2fGwi1" : true
    },
    "name" : "Ruben",
  },
  "senovi" : {
    "email" : "senovi",
    "groups" : {
      "-KB48kVOz4yTfdE86Ub7" : true
    },
    "name" : "Rubén ",
  }
 }
}
```

and this is what I've done so far in my security rules:

```
{
"rules": {
  ".read": true,
  ".write": true,
  "groups": {
    "$group_id": {
      ".indexOn": "members"
    }
  }
 }
}
```

This is the code that triggers the error:

```
DataService.dataService.GROUPS_REF.queryOrderedByChild("members/\(DataService.dataService.CURRENT_USER_ID)").queryEqualToValue(true).observeEventType(.Value, withBlock: { snapshot in
    //some code 
})
```

Comment: Please add the code that triggers the error.

Comment: I've edited the question with the code that triggers the error

Comment: Please don't store booleans as strings `"-KB422VV21cPzpgi1wF1" : "true"`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're trying to add an index on an array, which is not possible in Firebase.

As the error message tells you (it's surprisingly accurate), you need to add an index for `members/rsenov`:

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": true,
    ".write": true,
    "groups": {
      "$group_id": {
        ".indexOn": "members/rsenov"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

But this means you'll need to add an index for each user, which is very inefficient. That's why denormalization is recommended.

As an alternative (that I recommended in [answer to your last question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35514497/firebase-in-swift-nested-query-not-working-properly)) you can create an customized index yourself, a process known as denormalizing.

```
{
  "groups" : {
    "-KB422VV21cPzpgi1wF1" : {
      "author" : "rsenov",
      "members" : {
        "rsenov" : true
      },
      "name" : "Item 1"
    },
    "-KB423lni1Iptn2fGwi1" : {
      "author" : "rsenov",
      "members" : {
        "rsenov" : true
      },
      "name" : "Item 2"
    }
  },
  "users": {
    "rsenov": {
      "groups": {
        "-KB422VV21cPzpgi1wF1": true,
        "-KB423lni1Iptn2fGwi1": true
      }
    }
  }
}
```

With this data structure, you can look up the groups for a user without even needing a query:

```
ref.childByAppendingPath("users/rsenov/groups")
   .observeEventType(.Value, withBlock: { snapshot in
```

Or if you want to use the currently authenticated user:

```
ref.childByAppendingPath("users")
   .childByAppendingPath(ref.authData.uid)
   .childByAppendingPath("groups")
   .observeEventType(.Value, withBlock: { snapshot in
```

Comment: I tried before but it keeps showing same error, I don't really understand why

Comment: Ah hold on, you're trying to add an index on an array. That doesn't work.

Comment: This is actually how I have the data structured. I've updated my question with the whole JSON data structure. Since depending on which user is logged in, I can't look up the groups for the user with: `ref.childByAppendingPath("users/rsenov/groups")` because the user changes

Comment: Updated my answer. Please post a *complete* question from now on. These round trips are not very efficient.

Comment: A few days ago I was using this way to get the user groups 
`ref.childByAppendingPath("users")
   .childByAppendingPath(ref.authData.uid)
   .childByAppendingPath("groups")
   .observeEventType(.Value, withBlock: { snapshot in`
but in this way, after that you have to iterate through groups for each snapshot, and it wasn't efficient for some other reasons, so I made a question here and we decided to do it like the other way

Comment: If you are dynamically adding users to a group, you'll also need to add an index for each user. See the latest snippet of my answer for the right form for these indexes.

Comment: Thank you so much, I think I will move to the way you say to get the user groups

Answer (score 1):

For anyone getting a similar security warning with JSQMessages / Firebase you can use this.

```
{
"rules": {
    ".read": true,
    ".write": true,
    "typingIndicator": {
    ".indexOn": ".value"
  }
}
}
```