# Swift Firebase Snapshot to object model

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am working with a large firebase database with at least 6 layers of hierarchy as well as many children for each node. I wanted to parse the entire snapshot and convert it into an object model. I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35514497/firebase-in-swift-nested-query-not-working-properly) solution but in my opinion it is extremely inefficient as parsing each node's children requries a call to firebase and this increases latency exponentially. Is there any way for the "ref.observeSingleEvent" to be done locally instead of making a call to firebase? Any other better alternatives would be much appreciated.

Comment: Yes you can download a map in Firebase with many childerns under it, you do not have to make more than 1 call to Firebase if all childern fall under 1 map, and you download that map.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
//this goes into your call (observeSingleEvent)
let enumerator = snapshot.children //assuming you use snapshot as name
    while let rest = enumerator.nextObject() as? FIRDataSnapshot {
       // this loops through every child in that map   
      let values = (rest as! DataSnapshot).value as? NSDictionary
      let coins= values?["coins"] as? Int ?? 0 
      //above code looks for a key with username and grabs the value from that. If it is not a string value it returns the default value.
      //use above code for picture 1
      if (rest as! DataSnapshot).key == "slot"{
        let enumeratorMap1 = (rest as! DataSnapshot).children
        while let rest2 = enumeratorMap1.nextObject() as? FIRDataSnapshot { 
         let valuesMap1 = (rest2 as! DataSnapshot).value as? NSDictionary
         //loop through values in new map
        //use this methodes for looping through maps, as stated in picture 2
         //keep repeating this method for any child under the map
          }
       }
    }
```

Picture 1:
[image]

Picture 2:
[image]

Comment: This has resulted in a lot of bloated code but works way better than the other solution.

Comment: @tectonicpie yeah I know, but I think there is no other way (if there is, I would like to know), but it depends mostly on how you structure your data.

Comment: how do I make this solution work with arrays of objects? for example
"name" : [{object1},{object2},{object3}]
I can convert the name and its array to NSDictionary but once inside the array there are no key value pairs, just values for objects.