# How to get user_id from nested parent firebase

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want to retrieve sites information based on user_id , I am using following query to retrieve site information

```
ref = Database.database().reference()

        self.ref.child("sites").queryOrdered(byChild: "user_id").queryEqual(toValue:"DxMYXkVqnZMC6NEZxdSQF3G2ZJ53")
            .observe(.childAdded, with: { snapshot in

                if ( snapshot.value is NSNull ) {
                    print("Not found")


                } else {
                    print("found")


                }
            })
```

I am able to  call query if its store_name,idToken etc . But not able to call user_id because its inside a childbuAutoid

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You could create new a value listener for "users" then handle each child accordingly, or you could use a for loop to loop over the children, like so:

```
for child in snapshot.childSnapshot(forPath: "users").children
```

Answer (score 0):

Since your userID is nested, you need to keep looping your data that is why it looks ugly. Take a look at the following code, it should work. It just keeps looping through the values till it finds user_id. For more info with pictures, see my other answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45143371/7715250 It makes it more clear what something does do.

```
ref = Database.database().reference()

        self.ref.child("sites").observe(.childAdded, with: { snapshot in

                if ( snapshot.value is NSNull ) {
                    print("Not found")


                } else {
                 print("found")
                 let enumerator = snapshot.children
                 while let rest = enumerator.nextObject() as? FIRDataSnapshot {
                   if (rest as? DataSnapshot).key == "users"{
                   let enumerator2 = (rest as? DataSnapshot).children
                     while let rest2 = enumerator2.nextObject() as? FIRDataSnapshot {
                   for userID in (rest2 as? DataSnapshot).children{
                     let values = (userID as? DataSnapshot).value as? NSDictionary
                     let userId = values?["user_id"] as? String ?? ""
                      print(userId)
            }
         }
     }
   }
 }
})
```

Comment: Actually its not entering into either "not found" or "found"

Comment: @HaseenaPA I made a small change with the ref, it is weird it does not print anything. Do you have the full permission?

Comment: @HaseenaPA You can check out the link I provide in my answer, it gives you an idea how to loop through multiple data

Answer (score 0):

If you can change your database structure a little bit than you dont have to use all loopings.
You can change your database like the image below.
rather using autogenerated key you can use users id as key and put value whatever u like.

[image]

Now you write your query like this.(Sorry!! this code snippet is in java,Don't
know swift,but this will Help you).

```
dbr.child("sites").orderByChild("users/"+/*put user_id you want to search*/).equalTo("user_id").addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

           /*here you get the datasnapshot according to search*/

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
```

try to update your code.

```
self.ref.child("sites").queryOrdered(byChild: "users/"+"DxMYXkVqnZMC6NEZxdSQF3G2ZJ53").queryEqual(toValue:"user_id")
        .observe(.childAdded, with: { snapshot in

            if ( snapshot.value is NSNull ) {
                print("Not found")


            } else {
                print("found")


            }
        })
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: If we edit the current database structure it would be hard to handle it , is it possible to do with current structure

Comment: Yes but you need to do it with the coding ,get the values in the datasnapshots and then check for the user_id to be exist or not.