# Read Array from Firebase - Swift

Tags: arrays, swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am writing a function that allows me to read the data inside the Database. I can read the String from Firebase but I cannot read the arrays. I tried like this but it doesn't work:

```
func fetchData(collection: String) { 
    DatabaseFirestore.collection(collection).addSnapshotListener { (querySnapshot, error) in 
        guard let documents = querySnapshot?.documents else {
            print("No documents") 
            return
        }
        self.example = documents.map { (queryDocumentSnapshot) -> Example in
            let data = queryDocumentSnapshot.data()
            let ex1 = data["ex1"] as? String ?? "" // it is not an array in the database
            let ex2 = data["ex2"] as? String ?? "" // is an array in the database
            return Example(ex1: ex1, ex2: ex2)
        }
    }
}
```

How could I change this line so that it reads the array inside the database?

```
let ex2 = data["ex2"] as? String ?? ""
```

Comment: `as? [Any]` instead of `as? String`? But it's unclear what you need exactly since you are mixing Array & String.

Comment: ex1 is a String, ex2 is an array of strings within the database. I'm looking for a way to save it in variables.

Comment: if you cannot understand the difference between a `String` and an array of String, `[String]`, then it's time to read the basics again at: https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/TheBasics.html

Answer (score 0):

Casting as `[String]` instead of `String` might fix the issue

You also could check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45466718/retrieve-array-elements-from-firebase-in-swift) answer - it could be helpful when retrieving arrays and dictionaries from Firebase

Comment: If I write  " let ex2 = data["ex2"] as? [String] ?? "" "  gives this error: Cannot convert value of type 'String' to expected argument type '[String]'.

I tried to change it to this: " let ex2 = data["ex2"] as? [String] ?? [ ] ", and when I return the value I write: " return Example(ex1: ex1, ex2: ex2 as Any as! [String]) ".

If in the database there are no values ​​related to "ex2", and I try to print the value the app crashes. How can you make sure that if it finds no "ex2" value, it takes an empty string as a value?

I also tried this: let ex2 = data["ex2"] as? [String] ?? [ ""]

Comment: With `let ex2 = data["ex2"] as? [String] ?? []`, 
use `Example(ex1: ex1, ex2: ex2)`. Read the basics again, it will tell you, doing this:
 `Example(ex1: ex1, ex2: ex2 as Any as! [String])` is crazy.